# JavaFX - Adding shadow behind stage

Tags: javafx, shadow, stage

I wanna achieve something like this:

[image]

It should be a shadow behind the stage, but all I could do so far is shadow elements inside it or the stage itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a transparent stage and on the root pane you need to add a drop shadow